# Как вызвать экшн внутри другого экшна? Next Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, nextjs

У меня есть такой код:

```
'use client'

import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {getCookie} from '@/app/untils/Cookies';


const initialState = {
    userData: null
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "userData",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        checkUserToken: ()  => {
            console.log('chekc')
            const token = getCookie('user-token');
            console.log(token)
            if (token)
               return fetchUserData(token)
            else
                return fetchUserData(false)

        },
        fetchUserData: async (state, action) => dispatch => {
            return  console.log('FETCH')
            // console.log(state)
            // console.log(action)
        },
        setUserData: (state, action) => {
            console.log('SET USER')
            console.log(action)
            console.log(state)
        }
    }
})

export const {checkUserToken, fetchUserData, setUserData} = userSlice.actions

export default userSlice.reducer
```

Внутри checkUserToken я хочу вызвать fetchUserData, но как это сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте вызвать не `fetchUserData(token)` а `this.fetchUserData(token)`

Comment: @SwaD , Тогда выдаёт ошибку Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetchUserData')